# Lambda causes compile error "incompatible types" in Java 9, compiles in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-9

The following code compiles with Java 8 but not with Java 9:

```
public class CompileErrJdk9 {

    @FunctionalInterface public interface Closure<R> {
        R apply();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface public interface VoidClosure {
        void apply();
    }

    static <R> R call(Closure<R> closure) {
        return closure.apply();
    }

    static void call(VoidClosure closure) {
        call(() -> { closure.apply(); return null; });
    }

    static <T> void myMethod(T data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        call(() -> myMethod("hello")); //compile error in jdk9
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
CompileErrJdk9.java:24: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
        call(() -> myMethod("hello")); //compile error in jdk9
            ^
    upper bounds: Object
    lower bounds: void
  where R is a type-variable:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>call(Closure<R>)
1 error
```

I've narrowed it down to the type parameter `<T>` of `myMethod`; if I drop it and use `Object` for the parameter type the code compiles. Declaring `myMethod` as `static <T> void myMethod() { }` fails as well (in 9 only) even though I'm not using the type parameter.

I've checked the Java 9 release notes and searched for an explanation for this behaviour but did not find anything. Am I correct to assume this is a bug in JDK9, or am I missing something?

Comment: I agree this is a bug. I could reproduce it with Java 9. However, I couldn't reproduce it on Java 10 (10-ea+30).

Comment: Ok, seems like this is a genuine regression. I've sent a bug report to Oracle and will update accordingly once I receive a response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle has accepted this as a bug with ID JDK-8191290:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8191290

Update: the bug was closed with the comment "Fixed in 10, won't backport".